# "A play full of allusions to Shakespeare"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can you please explain to me how a play or movie could be full of allusions to someone like Shakespeare?

Do they give credit to these famous people or just make fun of them?

> The film is full of allusions to Hitchcock.
>
> A play full of allusions to Shakespeare.

Comment: It can be both. Allusions are basically just references. They can be serious, they can be admiring, they can be joking.

Comment: Typically these allusions are not to the artists themselves but to their works. In *Lola rennt*, for instance, there are allusions to Kubrick (the 'floating' telephone echoes the jawbone in the opening sequence of *2001:A Space Odyssey*), to Hitchcock (the many spirals and the portrait of Kim Novak echo *Vertigo*), and to Günter Grass (the glass-shattering scream echoes *Die Blechtrommel*). (I owe these references to my wife.)

Comment: Thanks.I got it.Can I say " scary movie series were completely (created on ) allusion to some blockbuster movies.."

Comment: An allusion is a passing reference like those I have cited, not a wide-scale recreation of another work's story or characters or style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As StoneyB comments, the name of a famous artist (playwright, novelist, movie director, etc.) is often used as a [synecdoche](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/synecdocheterm.htm) (a part representing the whole, or the whole representing a part) for *the [collective] works of that artist*.

So if someone says *"I studied Shakespeare at school"* it's quite possible they were never taught anything at all about the man himself, and his personal life (of which relatively little is known anyway). It's almost inconceivable they studied *all* of Shakespeare's works either - it's quite possible in such contexts to use the artist's name when in strictly literal terms you actually just mean *one* thing produced by that artist (which itself "stands in" for his total output, as a "typical" example).

Taken to extremes, thousands of people claim to have ["studied Homer"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fish%20gobbing%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22studied%20Homer%22) - but so far as I'm aware we don't even know enough about Homer to say whether one could meaningfully identify him as a single person.

And as oerkelens comments, *"allusions are basically just references"*. They might be positive, negative, neutrally informative, artistically creative/evocative, etc., depending on context.